# How can i set up the gcloud environment on Jenkins?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm currently using google text-to-speech api by choosing client library (Next.js).
In the docs, it needs to install gcloud cli and type some commands.
In local development, everything is fine with the commands.
To deploy, we installed the cli on the linux environment, which is our deploy environment.
And also we typed the exact same commands like we did in local development.
But it won't work in the deploy env.

So we concluded that there's gotta be something wrong with Jenkins env.
Is there a solution to set up with Jenkins?
We haven't tried anything about Jenkins because i can'f find the docs related.

Thank you.